# Processing actions in a single threaded fashion

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Lets say I have a class like follows:

```
class C
{
    Action _action;
    ...
    public C (Action<T> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Do (T x)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

What I want `Do` to do is to call `_action(x)` for every `x` exactly once, but, never have `_action` being called by two separate threads at the same time.

So if `Do(x1)` is called in thread 1, we should immediately start running `_action(x1)`. But if `Do(x2)` is called in thread 2 before `_action(x1)` completes, we should immediately return, but `_action(x2)` should be run in thread 1 when `_action(x1)` completes.

Note, for simplicity's sake assume `_action` doesn't throw.

If this class is only called with one thread there should be only one thread, I'd prefer not to have a separate thread on each end of this queue.

Is there a class that already exists that will help me set this up? Or even hints at some synchronization primitives might be useful? I'm thinking I could work this out with `Interlocked.Exchange` style calls, but I'm not sure if I should be using something less basic or if that's reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I suppose you need some kind of queue. Many threads can put data into the queue, but only one thread reads items from queue and execute. Is this scenario OK for you?

Comment: LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler might get you most of the way there? I can't remember when it runs synchronously, and when it uses the thread pool, if `ConcurrencyLevel` is 1. You used to be able to download it as part of a zip from MSDN, not sure where you can get it now.

Comment: TPL DataFlow [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=netcore-3.0) does exactly what you want - you just need to specify the degree of parallelism equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using an [`ActionBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) from the [TPL Dataflow library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library).

```
class C<T>
{
    private readonly ActionBlock<T> _actionBlock;

    public C(Action<T> action)
    {
        _actionBlock = new ActionBlock<T>(action);
    }

    public void Do(T item)
    {
        var accepted = _actionBlock.Post(item);
        Debug.Assert(accepted);
    }
}
```

In this example the `Post` method will always accept the item, because the `ActionBlock` is unbounded. If you later decide to impose a limit to the number of items that may be buffered by the block ([`BoundedCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity) option), then you'll need to rethink how to handle the case when the limit has been reached. Using `SendAsync().Wait()` instead of `Post()` is one way of handling this.

The TPL Dataflow library is embedded in the Core platform. For .NET Framework you need [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/).